# Basement Bathroom Plumbing - Rough in Backwater Valve

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, basement-refinishing, rough-in

I am trying to figure out how in the world to frame this basement bathroom.  As you can see from the image, there is a backwater valve that would end up right in the middle of the room.  I know that code requires access to this valve and most basement rough ins have this much closer to the sump pump or other mechanical area, not in the middle of the bathroom.

Any ideas for how I would be able to run walls for the bathroom?  I was planning to go off the pole and section off the room, but I dont know what to do since there will be a valve right next to the toilet.

What am I missing or am I looking at this all wrong?

Thanks for any help or answers you can provide!

[image: Layout]

[image: Room_Walls]

Advice? Do I need to jackhammer the floor to move the BWV closer to the sump pump?

Comment: Steve, you seem to be posting from two different profiles. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: What is on north of this drawing?  What is to the left of the furnace?  Is this  a living room area?  What is the distance from pole to wall for each pole?  Does this have a shower?

Comment: Which side of the drawing above is the street (since the main sewer line would generally exit in that direction.)  The Backwater valve is in an odd place, I will grant you.  If you aren't excited to break out the jackhammer you might be able to add a floor level cover, or hide the backwater valve under a cabinet with a removable bottom for access.

Answer (score 1):

While I totally agree it's the wrong place for the BWV, it's not sticking out of the floor. So, is your problem with doing a finished floor? As far as framing goes, I'd include the sump corner & make that whole end into a closet in the powder room.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should be able to move your backwater valve as close as you want to the pump, so long as you can access it for cleaning it out. I don't know where your actual drain lines are running, but I'm sure you can find somewhere else that will provide you with access to the BWV.[image]

Comment: I don't think it's a sewage ejector, the bwv doesn't tie in to the sump pump. The sump pump is for ground water.

Answer (score 0):

The important question here is where does your main building drain leave the house?Most Municipal codes require the Backwater valve to be the first fixture, if you put it after (upstream)of a floor drain or toilet,you can still flood your home if the city sewer backs up.If the main building drain leaves in the direction of the sump pit , move it closers to the pit and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work because you didn't give dimensions but you can try a configuration similar to the this

[image]

You can use the space by the sump pump as storage. Even the towel closet (with the bwv) could be accessible from the sump area instead of from the washroom.

You could try this.

[image]

Or this

[image]